# discard rows if at least one cell equals 0

Tags: r, subset

Example data frame:

```
test <- data.frame(A=c(0,1,2), B=c(0,2,3), C=c(0,1,0))
test
  A B C
1 0 0 0
2 1 2 1
3 2 3 0
```

What I am trying to get:

```
  A B C
2 1 2 1
```

When a row contains ≥1 cell equals to 0, discard it.

I am aware of the following, but I am looking for a more general solution, in the case I don't know how many columns my data frame is made of.

```
test[which(test$A !=0 & test$B !=0 & test$C != 0),]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` to subset the rows where there are no zeroes.

```
test[rowSums(test == 0) == 0, ]

#  A B C
#2 1 2 1
```

Comment: Woaw ! So reactive, I still have to wait 10 minutes before being able to validate the answer :-) Thanks !